# Как сформировать в jpa specification join запрос, если существует промежуточная таблица?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Есть 2 энтити:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Complex {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UserTable> users;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class UserTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Complex> complexes;
}
```

Для этой ситуации jpa создает промежуточную таблицу complex_users.

И вот вопрос, как правильно составить спецификацию, чтобы получить пользователей по энтити `Complex`?

Я пробую такой вариант:

```java
public class UsersSpec {
    public static Specification<User> find(UsersFilter usersFilter) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            final Collection<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            if(usersFilter.getComplex() != null) {
                predicates.add(root.join("complexes", JoinType.LEFT).in(Collections.singletonList(usersFilter.getComplex())));
            }
            else {
                predicates.add(root.join("complexes", JoinType.LEFT).isNull());
            }

            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
    }
}
```

Но jpa генерирует совсем не тот запрос, как будто он забывает о третьей таблице:

```sql
select ... from
    user_table user0_ 
    left outer join
    complex complexes1_ 
        on user0_.id=complexes1_.users_id 
    where
    (
        complexes1_.id in (55)
    )
```

Хотя должно быть так:

```sql
select ... from
    user_table user0_ 
    left join
    complex_users complexes1_ 
        on user0_.id=complexes1_.users_id 
    where
    (
        complexes1_.complex_id in (55)
    )
```

Как правильно составить join?

Comment: А разве правильно, то что у вас в двух связанных энтитях @OneToMany? Либо ManyToMany в каждой, либо в одной из них должно быть ManyToOne.

Comment: А как вы составите join если у вас сгенерированный запрос?

Comment: @Zhenyria если связь должна быть двунаправненой или же одной  однонаправленой тогда да, но если так как указано вышо то будет вместо одной двунаправленой связи или же  одной однонаправленой,  две однонаправленые, для которых Jpa создаст дополнительную таблицу

Answer (score 0):

При использовании спецификаций подразумевается, что запрос динамический и набор спецификаций может быть различным. В таком случае, лучше делать не одну спецификацию на все условия сразу, а по спецификации на каждое условие, которые не зависят друг от друга. `Join` в данном случае не очень подходит, тут лучше использовать `Subquery`.

```
public class UserSpecifications {
    public static Specification<User> containsComplex(Complex complex) {
            return (root, query, builder) -> {
                    Subquery<Complex> subquery = query.subquery(Complex.class);
                    Root<Complex> subqueryRoot = subquery.from(Complex.class);
                    Predicate predicateToJoin = builder.isMember(root,
                                                    subqueryRoot.get("users"));
                    if(complex != null) {
                       Predicate predicateByComplex = builder.equal(subqueryRoot, complex);
    
                       subquery.select(operation).where(predicateToJoin, predicateByComplex);
                       return builder.exists(subquery);
                    }

                    subquery.select(operation).where(predicateToJoin);              
                    return builder.exists(subquery).not();
            };
     }
}
```

Использование в проекте:

```
Specification spec = UserSpecifications.containsComplex(usersFilter.getComplex())
     .and(UserSpecifications.secondSpecification(usersFilter.secondParameter()))
     .and(UserSpecifications.thirdSpecification(usersFilter.thirdParameter()));

repository.findAll(spec);
```

Все спецификации должны возвращать предикат, а не `null`. Если спецификацию нужно проигнорировать исходя из значения параметра, то для этого есть `builder.conjunction()`, который вернет условия вида `1=1`. Есть также `builder.disjunction()`, который вернет условие `1=0`. Используют их следующим образом:

```
public static Specification<User> containsComplex(Complex complex) {
            return (root, query, builder) -> {
                    if(complex != null) {
                       return builder.conjunction(); //всегда истина, т.е. игнорируется
                    } else {
                       return builder.disjunction(); //всегда ложь
                    }
                    
            };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашим сущноснять вам нужна, @ManyToMany  (неважно двунаправленая или одно решайте сами)

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Complex {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
    private List<UserTable> users;
}


@Entity
@Table
public class UserTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
    private List<Complex> complexes;
}
```

и запрос с джоином, плюс к кому же поменять fetch = FetchType.EAGER на fetch = FetchType.Lazy что бы избежать N+1

```
@Query(value = "select u from User u left join fetch u.complexes c where c = :complex")
    User findByComplex (@Param(value = "complex") Complex complex);
```

или же вы можете сделать так как вы хотели через промежуточную таблицу если у вас будет не List сылка, а просто сущность, иначе отношение  @ManyToMany